# Django - Attach PDF to an e-mail which was generated by a view

Tags: django, django-views, email-attachments

I have a view which generates a PDF file and returns it as a HtmlResponse. Then the suitable URL shows that file. I want to be able to attach that pdf to an e-mail. Which is the best way to do this?

Any tips or examples are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EmailMessage.attach()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage)

Assuming you have a method `create_pdf` that creates your PDF, you should be able to do something like this:

```
pdf_content = create_pdf()
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'Body goes here', 'from@example.com',
        ['to@example.com'])
email.attach('document.pdf', pdf_content, 'application/pdf')
email.send()
```

Comment: Actually, one view creates the PDF and shows it in the browser. There is just one function.

Comment: To get more detailed help, you have to post some code.

Comment: @ibege Did you solve this problem? I would like to know please.